# How to implement Headless JS in react native android application?

Tags: javascript, react-native

**I need implement Headless JS in my React Native Android Application, but I got following issue :**

[image]

Here is My Code :

**index.android.js :**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import SomeTaskName from './SomeTaskName'
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SomeTaskName', () => SomeTaskName);
```

**SomeTaskName.js**

```
module.exports = async (taskData) => {
   alert('test');
}
```

**MyTaskService.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;
public class MyTaskService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
   @Override
   protected HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
   Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
     if (extras != null) {
        return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
          "MyTaskService",
          Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
         5000);
     }
     return null;
  }
}
```

and add service in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".MyTaskService" android:enabled="true" android:label="MyTaskService" />
```

Please , Anyone help to fix this issue.

Comment: Did this actually give out an alert?

Comment: could you make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register a headless task. So replace the following code:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SomeTaskName', () => SomeTaskName);
```

with:

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => SomeTaskName);
```

And you need to call the task from your service, so replace:

```
if (extras != null) {
    return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
      "MyTaskService",
      Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
     5000);
 }
 return null;
```

with:

```
// Following line just to be sure it does not silently fail
WritableMap data = extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : null;
return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
    "SomeTaskName", // Use the registered headless Task here
    data,
    5000);
```

Comment: Did you get the alert? @SaravanaKumar

Comment: Erorr: WritableMap data = extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : null;

Comment: this doesnt work, idk why is it chosen as correct answer

Comment: @NoilPaw I am not able to get the alert.. How to call a service in react-native android?