# React-Native Headless doubts

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, headless

I am new in React Native.

I was trying to make headless work following the official [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html) and other links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999330/how-to-implement-headless-js-in-react-native-android-application).

**The idea is the following:** 
Every one second the Headless Task increments 1 to a value in the Storage. Every 3 seconds the UI will read this stored value and display it to the user.
I ran it on my physical device without success.

**None of the tasks seems to be working or called. I don't know.**

**Thanks for your time and collaboration!**

**STEPS**

1-I've created an app using **react-native-cli**
    react-native init **monitorService**

2-In the root I've created a file **SomeTaskName.js**

3- in the folder android/app/src/main/java/com/monitorService I've created a file **MyTaskService.java**

4-Changed **AndroidManifest.xml** to include the service

5-Changed **App.js** to include the logic.

6-Changed **Index.js** to call the services

**"FILES OR COMMAND BY STEPS"**

1-`react-native init monitorService`

2-**SomeTaskName.js**

```
const internalWritting = null;

export default async (taskData) => {

        // do stuff
        console.log("TASK REGISTER DATA", taskData);

        this.intervalWritting = setInterval(async () => { 
            await AsyncStorage.getItem(SuperStoreServerConfig)
            .then(success => JSON.parse(success))
            .then((storedItem) => {
                if (storedItem) {
                    AsyncStorage.setItem(SuperStoreServerConfig, JSON.stringify(storedItem + 1))
                    .catch(err => {console.log(`error setting local storage ${err}`)});
                    return true;
                } else {
                    AsyncStorage.setItem(SuperStoreServerConfig, JSON.stringify(1))
                    .catch(err => {console.log(`error setting local storage ${err}`)});
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            })
            .catch(err => {console.log(`error ${err}`)});
        }, 1000);
};
```

3-**MyTaskService.java**

```
package com.monitorservice;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MyTaskService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
    private static final String TASK_NAME = "SomeTaskName";

    @Override
    protected @Nullable HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        WritableMap data = extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : Arguments.createMap();
        // WritableMap data = Arguments.createMap();

        int timeout = 30; //extras.getInt("timeout");
        Log.d(TASK_NAME, String.format("Returning HeadlessJsTaskConfig, timeout=%s ms", timeout));
        return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(TASK_NAME, data, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(timeout)
        );
    }
  }
```

4-**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.monitorservice">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.monitorservice.MyTaskService" android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

5-**App.js**

```
export const SuperStoreServerConfig = '@monitorService:serverConfig';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View, 
    AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { value: 0 };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.interval = setInterval(async () => { 
            await AsyncStorage.getItem(SuperStoreServerConfig)
            .then(success => JSON.parse(success))
            .then((storedItem) => {

                if (storedItem) {
                    this.setState({ value: storedItem });
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            })
            .catch(err => {console.log(`error ${err}`)});
        }, 3000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    render() {
        const msg = `To get started, edit App.js - ${this.state.value}`;

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                    Value readed from local storage!
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                    {msg}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});

export default App;
```

6- **index.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import SomeTask from '../monitorService/SomeTaskName';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('monitorService', () => App);
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => SomeTask);
// The intention of this second headless task is just logging. 
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('OtherTaskName', () => console.log('other task log'));
```

**adb logCat**

$ adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V BackgroundTask:V
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of main
03-22 17:24:04.614  9128  9128 ? SENTINEL_TAG: SENTINEL_MSG_LIBCUTILS
03-22 17:24:04.614  9128  9128 ? SENTINEL_TAG: SENTINEL_MSG_LIBLOG
03-22 17:54:50.388 10492 10492 ? SENTINEL_TAG: SENTINEL_MSG_LIBCUTILS
03-22 17:54:50.388 10492 10492 ? SENTINEL_TAG: SENTINEL_MSG_LIBLOG
03-22 18:31:04.408 14318 14381 ? SENTINEL_TAG: SENTINEL_MSG_LIBCUTILS
03-22 18:31:04.408 14318 14381 ? SENTINEL_TAG: SENTINEL_MSG_LIBLOG
03-22 18:32:52.652 15188 15188 ? SENTINEL_TAG: SENTINEL_MSG_LIBCUTILS
03-22 18:32:52.652 15188 15188 ? SENTINEL_TAG: SENTINEL_MSG_LIBLOG
03-22 18:33:47.819 15674 15722 ? SENTINEL_TAG: SENTINEL_MSG_LIBCUTILS
03-22 18:33:47.819 15674 15722 ? SENTINEL_TAG: SENTINEL_MSG_LIBLOG
03-22 18:33:47.868 15699 15699 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
03-22 18:33:47.913 15699 15699 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
03-22 18:33:47.913 15699 15699 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
03-22 18:33:47.955 15699 15699 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onReloadWithJSDebugger()
03-22 18:33:47.955 15699 15699 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
03-22 18:33:47.956 15699 15699 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
03-22 18:33:51.118 15699 15699 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onReloadWithJSDebugger()
03-22 18:33:51.118 15699 15699 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
03-22 18:33:53.639 16011 16011 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
03-22 18:33:53.670 16011 16011 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
03-22 18:33:53.670 16011 16011 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
03-22 18:33:53.709 16011 16011 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onReloadWithJSDebugger()
03-22 18:33:53.710 16011 16011 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
03-22 18:33:53.711 16011 16011 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
03-22 18:33:58.824 16011 16092 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
03-22 18:33:58.992 16011 16092 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
03-22 18:33:58.995 16011 16092 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
03-22 18:33:59.010 16011 16092 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
03-22 18:33:59.010 16011 16092 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
03-22 18:33:59.011 16011 16140 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
03-22 18:33:59.011 16011 16140 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
03-22 18:33:59.012 16011 16140 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
03-22 18:39:37.859 16877 16877 ? SENTINEL_TAG: SENTINEL_MSG_LIBCUTILS
03-22 18:39:37.859 16877 16877 ? SENTINEL_TAG: SENTINEL_MSG_LIBLOG

Comment: Can you provide the adb log here? 
Run the app on device and use  $ adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V BackgroundTask:V

Comment: Hi, HDevan, I added the log in the description

Answer (score 4):

> **Finally, I can fix the problem**.
>
> I have created a GitHub repo for the project if someone needs.
>   https://github.com/Iltony/monitorService
>
> **thanks!**
>
> **SomeTaskName.js**
>
> ```
> // I have to add this references to have the project running (not 
> // necessary to run the service) 
> import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'; 
> export const SuperStoreServerConfig = '@monitorService:serverConfig';
> ```
>
> **AndroidManifest.xml**
>
> ```
> // Added this permission (not necessary to run the service)
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
> ```
>
> **MainApplication.java**
>
> ```
> // The key is in this method, on the create I forget to start the
> // service
>
> @Override public void onCreate() {        
>     super.onCreate();     **      Intent
>     myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyTaskService.class);
>     getApplicationContext().startService(myIntent);
>     HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(getApplicationContext());
>     SoLoader.init(this, false);   
> }
> ```